# Adding Core-Plot Framework to my project is increasing size

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, core-plot

I have added coreplot frame work to my project referring the following site

http://recycled-parts.blogspot.com/2011/07/setting-up-coreplot-in-xcode-4.html

But This increases my project size to a large extent.Isn't this a matter of concern?

i am working on an expense tracker kind of application and this framework is increasing my app's size to 10MB. Should i stop worrying about it? or is there anything else i have to do with the framework.?

Answer (score 0):

As coreplot is not available on the target device, it has to be copied into your application bundle which naturally increases its size.

Comment: so Shall i leave it like that and continue with my project??

Answer (score 0):

your project has nothing to do with the size of your application , if that is what you are worried about , the size of you r application will be comparatively small when you build the application.